# Como validar telefone com sms React-Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, autenticação

No app em que estou trabalhando após fazer o login por facebook o usuário precisa preencher os dados dele, incluindo o telefone, mas preciso confirmar o telefone do usuário por sms antes de permitir ele salvar os dados

A autenticacao seria na mesma forma do accountkit porém o usuário já está logado

Existe algum modo de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar serviços como por exemplo https://www.twilio.com/sms. No caso, você gera um código, envia por SMS para o número e o usuário deve confirmar.